# Disabling/Enabling Pop up in browsers using Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application, I need to write code for enabling/disabling of browser pop up for some scenario. I searched on wed and tried many solutions but non of them seems to be working.

It will be very helpful for everyone if some one can provide solution of this problem in one discussion thread.

I am able to handle that is Chrome but I other not seems to be working. My code is:-

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: in Firefox you can do that using desired capabilities..If you would enter about:config in firefox and search for popup..you will see some properties with which u can play around for the same

Comment: When I using this for "dom.disable_open_during_load" taking reference from "http://superuser.com/questions/697018/how-to-disable-popups-in-firefox-without-add-ons" I am getting Exception stating "Preference dom.disable_open_during_load may not be overridden: frozen value=false, requested value=true"

Comment: aahh...in that case i would suggest you look for either AutoIT solution or Robot solution

Comment: Any news on this? Maybe, there is a work-around? I'm facing the same problem using python, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44277519/selenium-boolean-setting-in-aboutconfig-of-firefox-webdriver).