# Selenium: boolean setting in about:config of Firefox webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For a test suite, I'm running a python script controlling a Firefox instance using selenium webdriver. I want to change the setting `dom.disable_open_during_load` in about:config to `true`. Although this is the default setting in my default Firefox profile, selenium changes it to `false` (user-defined) whenever I'm starting a webdriver instance. It seems to use an anonymous, slightly changed profile?! I can then manually change it back, but I was struggling to do it with code: neither using a new profile nor using a pre-set profile configured with Firefox' profile manager solves the problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver

FFprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
FFprofile.set_preference('dom.disable_open_during_load', 'true')  # I also tried True, 1 - with and without quotes
# FFprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/ExampleUser/AppData/Local/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/owieroiuysd.testprofile')


FFdriver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=FFprofile)
FFdriver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

I can change various settings this way, but it doesn't work for this one. Where does the changed value `false` "user-defined" come from? Is it an automatic setting of selenium somewhere? I'm using:

- geckodriver 0.16.1
- selenium 3.4.2.
- Firefox 53.0.3 (64bit)
- python 3.4.4

**Edit:** I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36856920/disabling-enabling-pop-up-in-browsers-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java) on SO, dealing with the same problem in java.

If this turns out to be impossible, probably there is a nice work-around? Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']["dom.disable_open_during_load"] = True
```

Don't use `profile.set_preference('dom.disable_open_during_load', True)` as `profile.default_preference` will be overrided by frozen's.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please explain what your code does. If someone understood it without explanation, they probably would be able to write it themselves, anyway.

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late... Wow, this works, indeed! Thanks so much, there is no way I would have come up with this! :)

Comment: Read the source code  and debug it with Pycharm, and you will find it.

Comment: is this possible in NodeJS? how do we set it?

Answer (score 1):

`profile.set_preference('dom.disable_open_during_load', True)`

is the correct way to do it, but it won't work for this particular property as it's not allowed to change by user according to the following article. The same thing would work for other parameters.

i.e.

`profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)`

https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/mozilla_firefox/2015-06-30/finding/V-19743

**Solution**:

create a new profile and directly modify this setting in JS file. and then provide path of this local profile.  I have not tested this solution so not sure if it will work or not.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. However in your link, they refer to this setting being locked as "true", whereas in my case, it is `(user-defined) false` when I check it in about:config after the webdriver started. Referring to your suggestion: Which JS file do you mean? As stated above, I tried creating a separate FF profile using the profile manager, but this one setting is set to false anyway.

Comment: `prefs.js` file should be under profile folder, not sure if it will work or not.

Comment: Oh right, I found it. I added `user_pref("dom.disable_open_during_load", true);`, but it doesn't seem to effect the webdriver at all.

Comment: I found something very similar in java, see the edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This particular setting seems to be difficult for some reason...

Although I wasn't able to find a solution, I got inspired by [this webpage](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration) and found a decent work-around using Firefox' developer toolbar:

```
    ActionChains(self.FFdriver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.F2).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
    time.sleep(0.1)       // this seems to be necessary
    ActionChains(self.FFdriver).send_keys('pref set dom.disable_open_during_load true').perform()
    ActionChains(self.FFdriver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    ActionChains(self.FFdriver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys(Keys.F2).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

If anyone should know or find a better way, please comment!