# Modify security.enterprise_roots.enabled (or other about:config) in nodejs with selenium-webdriver using geckodriver

Tags: node.js, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

For my automation testing in NodeJS, I have the following script that creates a new instance of firefox and runs my script there

```
 const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

 let options = new firefox.Options().setBinary(os.homedir() + '/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe');     

 let driver = new webDr.Builder()
      .forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(options).build();
```

However, the page I am automating needs an additional requirement... I need to set `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to "true" (located in `about:config`)

[image: accessed by about:config]

I have changed the setting on my non-automated firefox browser. However, it seems that whenever I run the code above the driver reverts it back to "false".

How can I change this programmatically?

I saw this [answer but it is in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830557/2155668). How do you write the same code in NodeJS with selenium-webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was that I had to use a different profile instead.

Before building the automation, I set .Options().setProfile() as follows:

```
let options = new firefox.Options().setBinary(os.homedir() + 
 '/AppData/Local/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe').setProfile(os.homedir() + 
 '/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/(your profile.. it's a folder)');    

 let driver = new webDr.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(options).build();
```

This would run my firefox with the current settings I have with the profile, which includes `security.enterprise_roots.enabled = true`
 (or other about:config settings)